# What could be causing VS to have an error building taglib-sharp?

Tags: winapi, dll, build, building, taglib-sharp

Access denied from generating Win32 resource.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Screenshots escape text searches. If you can provide a textual representation, you should.

Answer (score 0):

Too much faff trying to figure out how to build it and no one gives a direct answer.

Just download the library [from NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/taglib/2.1.0) --> TagLib# 2.1.0

Fairly simple after that. Open the solution/project you want the library in, click on the "Tools" menu and locate where it either says...

```
NuGet Package Manager -OR- Library Package Manager
```

and to click on Package Manager Console.

A console appears and you type in after the "PM>"

```
Install-Package taglib
```

I'm pretty sure it's case-sensitive. If all things run smoothly, the console should write...

```
Installing 'taglib 2.1.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'taglib 2.1.0.0'.
Adding 'taglib 2.1.0.0' to <your solution/project name here>.
Successfully added 'taglib 2.1.0.0' to <your solution/project name here>.
```

Hope this works for you.